# Send username and password to a program using Matlab

Tags: matlab, exe, credentials

I'm trying to attempt an automated login (if possible) to a program that has not been designed by me, using Matlab.

The easy parts are clearing/closing all processes running and then starting the .exe file again. All of this occurs in this code:

```
function appRun
[~, progs]=system('tasklist /FI "imagename eq someApp.exe" /fo table /nh');
if ~isempty(strfind(progs, 'someApp.exe'))
    !taskkill -f -im EikonAPIProxy.exe
    fprintf('someApp has been closed for all users in the station \n')
else
    fprintf('someApp is not running on any of the users of this station \n')
end

fprintf('Starting someApp')
!"C:\myPath\someApp.exe" &

end
```

After this, the application starts good, but it requires user credentials to start functioning fully. I would like to know, if there's a way to it, how to pass login and password to such application.

Is something I've not attempted before and I didn't found much info (perhaps I didn't search properly). But in any case, if anyone can help, I'd be grateful.

Comment: How does the program get the username and password normally? Typing at a keyboard prompt, a dialog box, an API?

Comment: @AndersSandberg The application pops up a window with two clear fields to input ID and Password. I could use automatic login I guess, but that wouldn't be as robust as sending the credentials to the application. 

If there's a way to do so using the command prompt, then there should be a way to do it in Matlab, but I'm not even sure of the first one haha.